# Firefox does not align with right: as expected

Tags: css, firefox

So I have my set of nav pills again, however I noticed another odd issue.  I am using right: 5px to align the "notification" where I want it on the mobile view, which is less than 767 px.  Looks great in chrome, looks great in IE, however in firefox both of the "notification" spans are positioned on top of each other completely off of the LI's.  Any idea on why Firefox would be having such odd behavior?

HTML

```
  <ul id="contentFirstMenu" class="nav nav-pills">
    <li><a href="#">Item 1 Title</a><span class="notification">4</span></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 2 Title</a><span class="notification">0</span></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 3 Title</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 4 Title</a></li>
  </ul>
```

CSS

```
#contentContainer {
    padding: 20px 20px 50px 20px;
    margin-left: 100px;
}

#globalHeader {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.notesDropDown > li {
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    width: 132px;
    height: 35px;
    text-align: center;
}

.notesDropDownInner {
    text-align: left;
}

.notesDropDown li:first-child {
    border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
}

.notesDropDown li:last-child {
    border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
}

.notesDropDown li:only-child {
    border-radius: 5px;
}

#contentFirstMenu li:first-child {
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
}

#contentFirstMenu li:last-child {
    border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
}

#contentFirstMenu li:only-child {
    border-radius: 5px;
}

#viewFullText section {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.notification {
    color: #222;
    position: absolute;
    background: #fff;
    line-height: 12px;
    border: 1px solid #830600;
    border-radius: 15px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 12px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    padding: 2px 7px;
}

.dropdown-menu {
    min-width: 220px !important;
    padding: 5px !important;
}

.dropdown-toggle .caret {
    border-top-color: #999 !important;
    border-bottom-color: #999 !important;
}

.notesDropDown li.open .caret, .notesDropDown li:hover .caret {
    border-top-color: #fff !important;
    border-bottom-color: #fff !important;
}

#contentFirstMenu li.hover > a, #contentFirstMenu li:hover > a, #contentFirstMenu li.active > a, .notesDropDown li.open a, .notesDropDown li:hover a {
    color: #fff !important;
}

#contentFirstMenu > li {
    position: relative;
    float: none !important;
    width: 70px;
    background-color: #EEE;
    border: 1px solid #AAA;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(75, 75, 75, .5);
}

#contentFirstMenu a:hover, #contentFirstMenu > .active > a, .notesDropDown a:hover, .notesDropDown > .open > a {
    background-color: transparent !important;
    color: #FFF !important;
}

#contentFirstMenu a {
    color: #434343;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 12px !important;
    padding-top: 10px;
}

#contentFirstMenu li:active, #contentFirstMenu li:hover, #contentFirstMenu li.active, .notesDropDown > li:hover, .notesDropDown li.open {
    background-color: #434343;
}



#contentContainer div, #contentContainer span, #contentContainer textarea {
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #535353;
}

#contentFirstMenu{
    text-align: center !important;
    z-index: 100;
    position: fixed;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {

    #contentFirstMenu {
        top: 25%;
        margin-left: 10px;
    }
    #contentFirstMenu a {
        margin-top: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    .notification {
        left: 60px;
        top: 40px;
    }
}

/* smartphone css */

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    #contentFirstMenu {
        bottom: 5px;
        display: table;
        z-index: 100;
        clear: both;
        position: fixed;
        text-align: center !important;
        margin-left: 10px;
        margin-right: 10px;
        height: 45px;
    }

    #contentFirstMenu > li {
        float: none !important;
        display: table-cell !important;
        width: 25%;
        background-color: #EEE;
        border: 1px solid #AAA;
        margin: auto -5px;
        box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(75, 75, 75, .5);
    }

    .notification {
        top: -10px;
        right: 5px;
    }

    #contentFirstMenu li:first-child {
        border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
    }

    #contentFirstMenu li:last-child {
        border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
    }

    #contentFirstMenu li:only-child {
        border-radius: 5px;
    }

    #contentContainer {
        margin-left: auto;
    }
}
```

JS Bin with example

http://jsbin.com/ejetat/1/edit

Comment: Its working fine in firefox v20.0.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is a problem with Firefox understanding of the table-cell display.

```
#contentFirstMenu > li {
...
  display: table-cell !important;
...
}
```

Try changing this to:

```
  display: inline-block !important;
```

I think FireFox is a bit more fussy around the structure of 'CSS tables' and you do not seem to have a table-row so as an alternative, not tested, you could try wraping your `<ul>` in a `<div>`, give that `<div>` a display: table and give your `<ul>` a `display: table-row`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry for taking so long, this was the correct answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's because of your `li` being `display: table-cell !important;`

If you can change the markup slightly to have the `.notification` inside the link it'll be ok..

```
<li><a href="#">Item 1 Title<span class="notification">4</span></a></li>
```

and give the `#contentFirstMenu a` a `position:relative`

On the jsbin i've added my name in comments where the `position:relative` is

jsbin: http://jsbin.com/ejetat/2/edit